# JScrollPane shows blank space when children have overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery-jscrollpane

I am trying to use JScrollPane (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to render a div with children that have overflow:hidden.  When doing this JScrollPane renders but scrolling horizontally there is a large blank space where the overflowed text would have appeared.  Below is an image showing the problem as well as the relevant code and a JS fiddle showing the issue, if you scroll to the right you'll notice there is a large area showing which is what I am trying to remove.  Any ideas how to do so?

```
<div id="test" style="width:200px;overflow:auto;">
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').jScrollPane({});
});
```

[image: Example Image]

http://jsfiddle.net/yTaAS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the inner div takes the width the parent div #test. I replace your html as following and it is working now.

```
<div id="test" style="width:200px;overflow:auto;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in ligula id sem tristique ultrices eget id neque. Duis enim turpis, tempus at accumsan vitae, lobortis id sapien. Pellentesque nec orci</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: certainly better, but not the effect I'm looking for.  I don't want the horizontal scroll at all and I want the content truncated.  I can do this by setting the width of the inner div to 200px but I was trying to have the size set in percentages not a pixel size.  Does that make sense?  This is closer to what I am looking for, but I just want the information truncated.  The following shows what I want without JScrollPane and what is happening in JScrollPane.  http://jsfiddle.net/yTaAS/4/ notice the non JScrollPane version has no scroll bars.

Comment: really it is hard to understand your issue. could you please mention the exact output that you expect?

Comment: do u want to make the same effect with or without JScrollpane, check this : http://jsfiddle.net/pitchaip/x8bTh/1/

Comment: the last fiddle demonstrated what I was looking for, but it seems it's not possible to put something on my HTML to avoid this, I have to add a style to the jscrollpane generated class to get the desired effect.  Either way it works, thanks!